# tooltip not working when validating Xpage

Tags: tooltip, xpages

For a xp:inputTextarea element I have enabled a tooltip via attributes:

```
<xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="tooltip"></xp:attr>
<xp:attr name="data-placement" value="top"></xp:attr>
<xp:attr name="data-html" value="true"></xp:attr>
<xp:attr name="data-container" value="body"></xp:attr>
```

The text for the tooltip is set via the title property.

This works fine in edit mode but when I validate my xpage the tooltip is not rendered anymore.

When I expect the textarea in "normal" edit mode the data-original-title (containing the text in the title property) is rendered but not after validation.

What to do?

edit:

I added a computed text which should display a tooltip:

```
<xp:text escape="false">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return '<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="' + xptI18NBean.getValue("matter.gen_DescClientBusiness_Placeholder") + '">Notes</a> is my favorite database for building applications.';}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:text>
```

In edit mode the tooltip is rendered, when I inspect it I see:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="<h1>Hint</h1> <h5>domino is forever.</h5>">Notes</a> is my favorite database for building applications.
```

When I validate I see the data-original-title attribute is there but the tooltip will simply not be displayed with mouseover.

Edit:

adding some script seems to re-initiate the tooltip, even when validation fails:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: Does it work with `<xp:attr name="data-trigger" value="hover"></xp:attr>`?

Comment: no that does not work. a xe:tooltip keeps working though

Comment: You should add your last update to your question as an answer instead as I understand that this solves your issue